# How to catch exception in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In JSON parse, save the parsing data into NSDictionary, 
And read the `key-value` like:

```
NSString *verCode = [JSONDict objectForKey:@"v"];
```

but sometime, the key-value is other format, the program will crash, so I need covert to stringValue;
like this:

```
NSString *verCode = [[JSONDict objectForKey:@"v"] stringValue];
```

**How can I catch exception in iOS program?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use @try{ }  around code to catch exceptions.

In your case though a better approach is to look at the types of the object in the array for a key and use the right conversion as needed:

```
id object = [myJSONDict objectForKey:@"theValue"];

NSString *finalVal = nil;

if ( [object isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] )
  finalVal = [object stringValue]
else
  finalVal = object;
```

Comment: Agreed. JSON parsing is one of the few places that it is proper to explicitly check the class of the returned object.

Comment: Can it be another beside NSNumber?  Then how do you handle it?

Comment: JSON parsers will only return NSString and NSNumber for values - OR annoyingly sometimes NSNull (in which case you should just set your variable to nil or 0).  There is no real JSON date standard so you will not get back an NSDate.  You can also get back dictionaries and arrays of course, but those are sub-collections and not final values...