# handling Exceptions in objective c example

Tags: ios, ios4, xcode4, objective-c-blocks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to catch exception in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584687/how-to-catch-exception-in-ios)

how to implement try catch Exception handling in Xcode for standard exception of operation 
like number divided by zero .can provide some examples....

Comment: Didn't you look at Apple documentation?

Comment: Wouldn't *divide-by-zero* raise signal `SIGFPE`, rather than an exception?

Answer (score 1):

```
@try {
    ...
}
@catch (CustomException *ce) {   // 1
    ...
}
@catch (NSException *ne) {       // 2
    // Perform processing necessary at this level.
    ...

}
@catch (id ue) {
    ...
}
@finally {                       // 3
    // Perform processing necessary whether an exception occurred or not.
    ...
}
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocExceptionHandling.html

Answer (score 0):

Try/catch seems to be frowned upon in Objective-c. Generally an NSError parameter is passed by reference. See [this tutorial](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/04/cocoa-tutorial-using-nserror-to-great-effect/) for example code.